# How To Specify Max Image Width And Hieght In Imacros Script For SAVEAS Command

Tags: firefox, screenshot, imacros

I am currently using this script for taking screenshots on Firefox

```
VERSION BUILD=7210419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TITLE ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=* FILE={{!VAR1}}.png
```

Now, my question is, how do I specify a particular size of image to save?

I have checked out [Save As Command](http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS) on wiki page of imacros but I can't see anything there...

Comment: By size of image, do you mean that you want to extract a screenshot of a segment of the page or resize the screenshot to a given pixel size?

Comment: i want to specify pixels like 10000 * 10000 so that image i grab by screenshot is of size 10000 * 10000